# Big-O complexity of random.choice(list) in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, complexity-theory

What is Big-O complexity of random.choice(list) in Python3, where n is amount of elements in a list?

Edit: Thank You all for give me the answer, now I understand.

Comment: If it's not stated in the specification, it's presumably implementation-dependent.

Comment: I can't imagine any reason why it wouldn't be `O(1)`. It just needs to pick a random number `i` from `0` to `len(list)`, then return `list[i]`. They're all constant-time operations.

Comment: If Python lists were implemented as linked lists, it would be `O(n)`, since getting the length of a list is linear, as is accessing a selected element. But since they're actually arrays, everything is constant.

Answer (score 19):

`O(1)`. Or to be more precise, it's equivalent to the big-O random access time for looking up a single index in *whatever* sequence you pass it, and `list` has `O(1)` random access indexing (as does `tuple`). [Simplified, all it does is `seq[random.randrange(len(seq))]`, which is obviously equivalent to a single index lookup operation.](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/random.py#l259)

An example where it would be `O(n)` is `collections.deque`, where indexing in the middle of the `deque` is `O(n)` (with a largish constant divisor though, so it's not that expensive unless the `deque` is reaching the thousands of elements range or higher). So basically, don't use a `deque` if it's going to be large and you plan to select random elements from it repeatedly, stick to `list`, `tuple`, `str`, `byte`/`bytearray`, `array.array` and other sequence types with `O(1)` indexing.

Comment: What do you mean with "largish" constant divisor?

Comment: @StefanPochmann: Implementation details here, but CPython's `deque` is a linked list of blocks that each store [up to 64 values](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/c445746d0846/Modules/_collectionsmodule.c#l21) (the left and right blocks may be incomplete). Until the length crests 66, no lookup can require any block traversal, and even up to a thousand elements, you're still looking at a maximum of 17 blocks (at most half of which must be traversed for indexing), and the Python interpreter overhead generally swamps small C level costs like traversing 8 hops in a linked list.

Comment: Oh cool, I had no idea it does that. But makes sense. Thanks, nice to know.

Comment: Does O(1) still hold true if I'm using a weighted random choice? https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices
Similar to setting [p in `np.random.choice()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) rather than using a uniform distribution?

Comment: @CGFoX: Weighted choice for `choices` is `O(n log m)`, where `n` is the number of choices being made, and `m` is the total number of weights (it bisects the cumulative weights for each choice, which is `O(log m)` work, and does that `n` times). So it's still `O(1)` per selection in terms of the sequence being selected from (excluding cases like `deque`), it's just a tiny bit more expensive to weight the choice.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply! Without using `random.choice`, would it still be possible to achieve O(1) for a weighted choice if I do some pre-processing? I could randomly select some `i` in the range of all summed up weights in O(1). And then use a hash table to map the selected `i` to one of the `n` choices in O(1). Would require pre-processing and extra memory but allow weighted random choice in O(1), right?

Comment: @CGFoX: Providing cumulative weights instead of relative weights saves preprocessing from relative to cumulative. Improving on that would require you to make a side-band `list` that described each index `x` number of times (e.g. if index `0` was 10% likely, and `1` was 90% likely, you'd make a list `[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]`, do a `O(1)` selection from that and then do a `O(1)` lookup of the original source `list`). But that side-band `list` has a minimum size equal to the original `list`, and for weird percentage weights, it could occupy all your memory. `O(log m)` is cheap enough.

Comment: Just to clarify: If I limit myself to integer percentages as cumulative weights, I'd have a side-band list of size 100 (from 0% to 100%) and could achieve O(1) look up?

Comment: @CGFoX: Not in the design I mentioned, where each index in the side-band list corresponds to an index in the main list (which is the only way to individually weight indices in the main list while preserving `O(1)` work). Cumulative weights must be searched; since it's a binary search strategy, that's `O(log m)` in the number of weights. If you limit yourself to integer cumulative weights, that's pretty cheap anyway (log₂100 is less than 7, which is not likely to kill you, perf-wise); I'm not sure why you're so insistent on `O(1)`, when it's going to cost so much on preprocessing and memory.

Answer (score 8):

Though the question is about `random.choice` and previous answers on it have several explanations, when I searched for the complexity of `np.random.choice`, I didn't find an answer, so I decide to explain about `np.random.choice`.

choice(a, size=None, replace=True, p=None). Assume `a.shape=(n,)` and `size=m`.

When with replacement:

The complexity for `np.random.choice` is O(m) if `p` is not specified (assuming it as uniform distribution), and is O(n + n log m ) if `p` is specified.

The github code can be find here [np.random.choice](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/2eedaa4cf94cf54bbd4d8428aa39271410f22e9f/numpy/random/mtrand.pyx#L804).

When `p` is not specified, `choice` generates an index array by `randint` and returns `a[index]`, so the complexity is O(m). (I assume the operation of generating a random integer by randint is O(1).)

When `p` is specified, the function first computes prefix sum of `p`. Then it draws m samples from [0, 1), followed by using binary search to find a corresponding interval in the prefix sum for each drawn sample. The evidence to use binary search can be found [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/feb0794bdb6709861b395818ddf0ea3548310e24/numpy/core/src/multiarray/item_selection.c#L1776). So this process is O(n + m log n). If you need a faster method in this situation, you can use [Alias Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_method), which needs O(n) time for preprocessing and O(m) time to sample m items.

---

When without replacement: (It's kind of complicated, and maybe I'll finish it in the future.)

If `p` is not specified, the complexity is the same as `np.permutation(n)`, even when m is only 1. See more [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/2764).

If `p` is specified, the expected complexity is at least $n \log n \log\frac{n}{n + 1 - m}$. (This is an upperbound, but not tight.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer on np.random.choice, can you please specify better why:
""When p is not specified, choice generates index by randint and returns a[index], so the complexity is O(m).""
Doesn't python have O(1) time complexity when it performs lookup on lists?
Here's a link: https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity
Thanks

Comment: @eracle: Thanks for your comment. I've updated the answer and make it clear that we use `np.random.choice` to sample `m` samples from an array of length `n`. In the situation you mention, we need O(m) time to generate an index array of size `m` and performs `m` lookups. However, I've assumed that using `np.random.randint` to sample a random integer needs O(1) time. I'm not really sure about this assumption.

Comment: ```The complexity for np.random.choice is O(m) if p is not specified (assuming it as uniform distribution), and is O(n + n log m ) if p is specified.``` . ```O(n + n log m )``` should be ```O(n + m log n )```

Answer (score 5):

The complexity of random.choice(list) is O(log n) where n is the number of elements in the list.

The cpython implementation uses [_randbelow(len(seq))](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/random.py#l262) to get a pseudo-random index and then returns the item at that [index](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/random.py#l265).

The bottleneck is the [_randbelow()](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/random.py#l229) function which uses rejection sampling to generate a number in the range [0, n). The function generates k pseudo-random bits with a call to [getrandbits(k)](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/random.py#l239) where k is ceil(log N). These bits represent a number in the range [0, 2**k). This process is repeated until the generated number is less than n. Each call to the pseudo-random number generator runs in O(k) where k is the number of bits generated which is O(log n).

Answer (score -2):

I think the above answer is incorrect. I empirically verified that the complexity of this operation is `O(n)`. Here is my code and a little plot. I am not sure about the theory though.

```
from time import time
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
N = np.logspace(2, 10, 40)
output = []
for i, n in enumerate(N):
    print(i)
    n = int(n)
    stats = time()
    A = np.random.choice(list(range(n)), n//2)
    output.append(time()-stats)   
plt.plot(N, output)
```

This is the plot I got which looks quite linear to me. 
[image: Complexity of np.random.choice]

Comment: The runtime of the test you performed is dominated by the list(range(n)) which creates a list of length n. That operation is O(n). You want to generate the list before staring your timer so that it only includes the np.random.choice function.

Comment: I'd also suggest using the using the `timeit` module, and using a `loglog` plot, otherwise you're not going to see the small `N`s