# Replicating MATLAB's `randperm` in NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, performance, matlab, random

I want to replicate MATLAB's [`randperm()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randperm.html) with NumPy.

Currently, to get `randperm(n, k)` I use `np.random.permutation(n)[:k]`. The problem is it allocates an array of size `n` then takes only `k` entries of it.

Is there a more memory efficient way to directly create the array?

Comment: Does MATLAB do something different?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comparison of np.random.choice vs np.random.shuffle for samples without replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65218695/comparison-of-np-random-choice-vs-np-random-shuffle-for-samples-without-replacem)

Comment: What are your typical n,k values? If n is huge and k is small, you could get away with some custom implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`numpy.random.choice(n, k, replace=False)` is no more memory efficient than `numpy.random.permutation(n)[:k]`. It too creates an `n`-item temporary list, shuffles that list, and takes `k` items from that list. See:

- [Comparison of np.random.choice vs np.random.shuffle for samples without replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65218695/comparison-of-np-random-choice-vs-np-random-shuffle-for-samples-without-replacem)

However, `numpy.random.*` functions, such as `numpy.random.choice` and `numpy.random.permutation`, have become legacy functions as of NumPy 1.17, and their algorithms — inefficiencies and all — are expected to remain as they are for backward compatibility reasons (see the recent [RNG policy for NumPy](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/doc/neps/nep-0019-rng-policy.rst)).

Fortunately, NumPy since version 1.17 has an alternative:`numpy.random.Generator.choice`, which uses a much more efficient implementation, as can be seen below:

```
In [227]: timeit np.random.choice(4000000, 48, replace = False)                                  
163 ms ± 19.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. Dev. Of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [228]: timeit np.random.permutation(4000000)[:48]                                             
178 ms ± 22.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. Dev. Of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [229]: r=numpy.random.default_rng()                                                           

In [230]: timeit r.choice(4000000,48,replace=False)                                              
14.5 µs ± 28.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. Dev. Of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

If you use NumPy 1.17 or later, you should make use of the new pseudorandom number generation system introduced in version 1.17, including `numpy.random.Generator`, in newer applications.

Comment: Any chance to have memory consumption analysis as well?

Comment: I don't know how to analyze memory consumption of Python code, as least not as easily as time consumption.

Answer (score 2):

I can recommend you `np.random.choice(n, k, replace = False)`.
Yet, I am not sure about memory efficiency.
Please refer to [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html)

Comment: I added `replace = False` which is a must to replicate MATLAB's behavior. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @[TaQ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10972919/taq) answer:

```
np.random.choice(n, k, replace = False)
```

Is the equivalent to MATLAB's `randperm()`.

Update: I will update his answer as well to mark it.