# Recreate randperm Matlab function in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matlab, random, permutation

I have searched on stackoverflow for people facing similar issues and this topic [Replicating MATLAB's `randperm` in NumPy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73266806/replicating-matlabs-randperm-in-numpy) is the most similar.

However, although it is possible to recreate the behavior of randperm function from Matlab in Python using numpy random permutation, the numbers generated are not the same, even though I choose the same seed generator for both languages. I am a bit confused since my tests were relevant for other random functions between Matlab and Python.

Here is what I have tried:

Matlab

```
rng(42);
randperm(15)
```

which returns

```
ans =

    11     7     6     5    15    14     1     4     9    10     3    13     8     2    12
```

Python

```
np.random.seed(42)
print(np.random.permutation(range(1,16)))
```

which returns

```
[10 12  1 14  6  9  3  2 15  5  8 11 13  4  7]
```

How can I change my Python code so it can reproduce the same order of random numbers than Matlab ?

Comment: if you want to guarantee the equality of outcomes, call Matlab from Python using its API. Otherwise, you either know that their random generation algorithm is equal or you have no guarntee.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that Matlab and Numpy use the **same random number generators** by default, and the discrepancy is caused by the **inner workings of `randperm` being different** in the two languages.

In old Matlab versions, `randperm` worked by generating a random array and outputting the indices that would make the array sorted (using the second output of [`sort`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html)). In more modern Matlab versions (I'm using R2017b), `randperm` is a built-in function, so the source code cannot be seen, but it seems to use the same method:

```
>> rng('default')
>> rng(42)
>> randperm(15)
ans =
    11     7     6     5    15    14     1     4     9    10     3    13     8     2    12
>> rng(42)
>> [~,  ind] = sort(rand(1,15))
ind =
    11     7     6     5    15    14     1     4     9    10     3    13     8     2    12
```

So, if the random number generators are actually the same in the two languages, which seems to be the case, you can replicate that behaviour in Numpy by defining your own version of `randperm` using [`argsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html):

```
>>> import numpy as np
np.random.seed(42)
ind = np.argsort(np.random.random((1,16)))+1
print(ind)
[[11  7  6  5 15 16 14  1  4  9 10  3 13  8  2 12]]
```

Note, however, that relying on the random number generators being the same in the two languages is risky, and probably version-dependent.

Comment: I sometimes am deeply surprised learning that MATLAB implements a weird, sub-optimal algorithm for a standard task with a standard, efficient solution.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Do you mean [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_permutation#Fisher-Yates_shuffles)? That seems to be linear, an sorting is about n*log(n). so not much more expensive. Also, the linear algorithm requires looping, which was an issue in old Matlab versions. Note that `randperm` was an m-file. And you have to admit that `[~, out] = sort(in);` looks elegant :-)

Comment: I guess the sorting method is more efficient if you don’t have a JIT and can rely on fast, vectorized `sort` and `rand`. But in a compiled language it’s much less efficient, it uses more memory and sorting is a lot more expensive. O notation talks about how it scales with array size, not about how much it costs. Fisher-Yates doesn’t use any comparisons at all, sorting needs to do O(n log n) comparisons. Sorting also needs to move each array element multiple times, Fisher-Yates does exactly n-1 swaps.