# Performance of Random number generators of pyroot and random

Tags: python, random, pyroot

I was looking to optimize a simple given code that generates a random number ([0,1,2]) that is not in a given list. The random number generator is TRandom3 from ROOT.

```
def getNumber(noList, randomgen):
    #Fügen Sie hier Ihren Code ein!: 
    i = randomgen.Integer(3)
    while i in noList:
        i = randomgen.Integer(3)
    return i
```

It is very basic and just generates new numbers until an allowed one is reached.

My own optimized code looked like this:

```
def bessereAuswahl(noList):
    return random.choice([elem for elem in [0,1,2] if elem not in noList])
```

I just remove all not allowed numbers from my list [0,1,2] and use random.choice to pick one element.

Running on windows 10 I had a performance increase, running the same code on linux I had a performance decrease.

Why is that the case?

Is there a hidden performance penalty for random on linux or is it a performance boost in pyroot?

Comment: I find your setup a little weird, so you have a number room I that is split in I1 allowed numbers and I2 forbidden numbers and you draw numbers from I until you draw one from I2? Or what is the goal?

Comment: yea, that is the idea.
I draw from my numbers [0,1,2] until I draw one that is not in my second list.
As this has the problem of a theoretical infinite runtime I wrote the second bit of code that I though would be faster but is for some reason only on Windows not on Linux. And i want to know why it is only faster on Windows.

Comment: Does my answer answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

So this is an implementation and complexity question:

the random.choice is implemented as:

```
The complexity of random.choice(list) is O(log n) where n is the number of elements in the list.
```

More on that second answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40143157/q-what-is-big-o-complexity-of-random-choicelist-in-python3)

Whereas a random integer generation with Mersenne Twister agorithm is `O(1)`, source code [here](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.4/Modules/_randommodule.c#l93)

So the first part of the answer is, that asymptotically `choice` is slower. However, the question is, if you have to generate a certain amount of numbers.

So if you have to create n numbers and the set of allowed numbers in the total set is relatively small, the amount of retrials can grow more significantly than the individual runtime of draws

Comment: Thanks, but do you know why the runtime is different between Windows and Linux?

Comment: how large was the sample you used to test runtime?

Comment: I tested 100000 times 
```getNumber([], generator)
    getNumber([1], generator)
    getNumber([1,2], generator)
    getNumber([numberOne], generator)
    getNumber([numberOne], [numberTwo], generator) ```
so I had a large enough sample size. Runtime on my Windows machine is around 0.5s for ```bessereAuswahl()``` and 0.7s for ```getNumber()```.
On linux it was 2.9s for ```bessereAuswahl()``` and 2.2s for ```getNumber()```.

Comment: Both windows and Linux deployed on bare metal or one as a vm within the other?

Comment: well, your test environment seems absolutly fine, so unfortunatly I don't have another idea.. sorry mate